# Loop through groups of input fields and do simple math

Tags: jquery, each, onchange, onkeyup

I have a group of inputs that will be used multiple times within the same form. Each group is independent of each other.

I'm trying to write efficient jQuery that will loop through each group of inputs and watch for changes. Each `input.total` field should be autofilled with its respective value. The simple math for each group is as follows:

`input.total = input.price * input.qty`

```
<!-- Repeatable Section -->
<div class="payment-type">
  <!-- Reveals the div below if checked -->
  <input type="radio">
  <label>Pay As You Go</label>

  <div class="reveal-if-active">
    <label>Price</label>
    <input class="require-if-active price" type="text">

    <label>Quantity</label>
    <input class="require-if-active qty" type="text">

    <!-- Total = Price * Qty -->
    <label>Total</label>
    <input type="number" class="total" value="" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post jquery code (for your loop) as well

Comment: As I am a novice at jQuery, I have trashed all of my attempts.

Answer (score 0):

There was an answer posted that seems to have been since deleted. Their answer seemed to not work with multiple groups of `.payment-type`. So I modified it to fit my needs. It seems to calculate the `number.total` field by multiplying its sibling fields correctly.

```
// Calculate Form Fields

$("input.price").on("keyup", function(){
  $(this).siblings("input.total").val((

    $(this).val() * $(this).siblings("input.qty").val()
  ).toFixed(2));
});

$("input.qty").on("keyup", function(){

  $(this).siblings("input.total").val((

    $(this).val() * $(this).siblings("input.price").val()
  ).toFixed(2));
});
```